# How am I supposed to use *status in waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options)?

Tags: c, linux, status, waitpid

I don't understand what `*status` is supposed to do, or what he is doing.

There's an example below; could you explain what `stat_cliente` is doing?

```
for(int i = 0; i < Config.CLIENTES; i++){
    int stat_cliente;

    waitpid(Ind.pid_clientes[i], &stat_cliente,0);
    if(WIFEXITED(stat_cliente)){ // Se terminou normalmente WIFEXITED devolve true
        int status = WEXITSTATUS(stat_cliente); // WEXITSTATUS devolve os 8 bits menos

        if(status < Config.SERVICOS){   // significativos do status usado no
                                        // exit do filho

            Ind.servicos_recebidos_por_clientes[status]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [waitpid man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)? It does explain it there quite clearly. If you still don't understand it can you please be more specific what part you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As widely described [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), `waitpid()` is one of the functions to make a *father process* wait for a *child process* status change after a `fork()`. That's mainly used to terminate correctly child processes and to release their resources.

There's no need to replicate the complete manual page explanation. Lets just say that in

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

- **pid** is the process ID of the child process to wait for. This is the parameter distinguishing this function from its "sisters", because it allows to wait for a *specific* process. Well, it also allows to wait for *groups* of processes; read the manual for further clarifications.
- **status**. It is a pointer to integer in which `waitpid()` will store the new status.
- **options** specifies the behavior of the function (allowing for example to work in non-blocking mode). See the manual for a deeper explanation.

---

### About `status` parameter

So, to answer your question, what's the meaning of *status* parameter? And why it is a *pointer* to integer? **Passing variables like pointers is often an alternative way to output something.**

So this function has actually **two** outputs: the changed pid (through the return value) and the new status, written in address you provided to it (unless the address is NULL).

---

### Code analysis

1. There's a loop on a known number of clients defined within `Config.CLIENTES`
2. The program waits for the status change of each client, the `stat_cliente` variable is filled with the new state of that process (in fact, it address, a `int *` is passed to `waitpid()`). **Warning**: there's no check on the return value of `waitpid()`, that could actually return -1 in case of error. In that case `stat_cliente` 's value would be meaningless!
3. The program checks if the child process exited normally through `WIFEXITED()` macro
4. In case of normal termination, `WEXITSTATUS()` macro can be called in order to retreive the exit status
5. For a limited subset of the child processes (those classified as services, I suppose, since the check against `Config.SERVICOS` is performed) increase the specific counter of the found status for the current service.

**In conclusion**, this program portion performs two tasks:

1. It makes sure that all child processes terminate gracefully through `waitpid()`.
2. It updates a statistic table for a subset of them, called "services", in order to trace along the history the occurrence of all their possible termination causes for each of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having trouble understanding how status works. I could see that it was a pointer, but wasn't comprehending how it would retrieve the exit() of a child process.

Have a great day!